# creating module error in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I have this warning:

> "Your PHP configuration must be changed to allow files of at least 6MB
>   to be uploaded. Please modify the upload_max_filesize value in your
>   php.ini located at: C:\xampp\php\php.ini"

I have edited and save it to 6MB, however, I am still unable to deploy my module and the error still appears. Really appreciated for kind help. Thanks

Comment: 1) Did you restart Apache? 2) try to put more than 6MB, 32MB, still not a high value, but still better than exactly 6MB

Comment: yes i restarted it and used 32 MB but the error still appears :(

Comment: try to have sugarcrm to generate for you a diagnostic log, it includes all the parameters it sees. It could be that you are NOT changing the right value, as you might notice ``php.ini`` has multiple instances (appearances) on your file system

Comment: how do i get sugarcrm to generate it for me?

Comment: This is found in sugar system log after i tried to deploy a module(pointsredemption):
[2504][1][FATAL] ERROR: rmdir_recursive(): argument custom/modulebuilder/packages/PointsRedemption is not a file or a dir.

Comment: I suggest you contact SugarCRM's support staff or contact the person that wrote the PointsRedemption module